# HTTP 301 redirect url encoding issue

Tags: python, html, encoding, python-requests, mojibake

I'm using Python's requests.get() to get some Facebook profiles HTML.
Some of them redirect the request to a new url. When this new url has special characters, such as **'á'**, the request.get() method enters a redirect loop until an exception is raised. I found a workaround to correct the redirect url string, found in the response header under the "Location" key, but it is far from an elegant solution.

```
import requests

# This case works. Response [200]
r = requests.get('https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=4')
print(r)

# This fails. Redirect location has special characters.
# raises requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
not_working_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100010922979377'
try:
    r = requests.get(not_working_url)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)  # Exceeded 30 redirects.

# Workaround
r = requests.get(not_working_url,
                 allow_redirects=False)
redirect_url = r.headers["Location"]
print(redirect_url)
# "https://www.facebook.com/people/TomÃ¡s-Navarro-Febre/100010922979377"
# Special character 'á' on "/Tomás_Navarro_Febre/" is displayed as 'Ã¡'.

# This fixes the string.
redirect_url = redirect_url.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf-8')
print(redirect_url)
# "https://www.facebook.com/people/Tomás-Navarro-Febre/100010922979377"

# Now it works. Response [200]
r = requests.get(redirect_url)
print(r)
```

There must be a better way to deal with this. I tried a bunch of different headers, and using requests.Session(), but none of them worked. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's a Mojibake; encode to Latin-1 instead.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the most current versions of requests, and I see code specifically aimed at avoiding this problem. What version are you using?

Comment: I was using 2.12.4. I just updated to 2.19.1 and it worked. Thank you so much. So much time wasted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headers are normally encoded as Latin-1, so that's what `requests` uses to decode all headers. However, in practice, the Location header usually uses UTF-8 instead. What you are seeing then is a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), in this case UTF-8 data decoded as Latin-1.

As of requests 2.14.0 (released May 2017), the library [specifically decodes the Location header as UTF-8](https://github.com/requests/requests/commit/722b1dae96b0523dde5e01351dd743f102090f53), precisely to avoid the problem you encountered. Upgrade your requests library.

If you can't upgrade, you can subclass the `Session` class to 'patch' the issue locally:

```
class UTF8RedirectingSession(requests.Session):
    def get_redirect_target(self, resp):
        if resp.is_redirect:
            return resp.headers['location'].encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
        return None
```

then use

```
with UTF8RedirectingSession() as session:
    response = session.get(...)
```